# How to send data from google tag manager ( GTM ) to google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am using Google BigQuery for storing user's analytics from my site.

User's Tag data is stored by using GTM datalayer

My Question: How to send data from GTM to Google BigQuery?

Comment: Have you tried this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer?

Comment: what do you mean? you want the Google Analytics data? Why would you want to import directly directly on BigQuery, It will be more accurated to use Google Analytics and them export to BigQuery(Feature only enabled to premium users.) Also take in consideration if you use javascript to send data, you need to share the credentials with the client, this will create a security breach.

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza basically i am storing analytics for each user and each action on my site.... which can't possible with google analytics.....

Comment: for that I want to store all data in bigquery and then i want to use it for my notifications and other purposes

Comment: GTM does not collect data, it merely relays them to other systems, so you'd need to write your own collector first that is integrated via GTM and then writes the data to BigQuery (or possibly do the collecting first and then import in bulk). How to do this might be a bit to broad a question for SO.

Comment: For a basic idea you could look at this article: https://www.simoahava.com/google-cloud/scrape-domain-and-write-results-to-bigquery/ (you would want to replace the web scraper by something that extracts data from the page, but the principle is not too different).

Comment: @HaseebAhmad have you managed to solve this? I see others asking [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55761116/1031958)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to collect event data from the users.

I can offer 2 different options for it:
Easy and common one is, you can send your data to Google Analytics, and then export it to BigQuery daily.

The second one is, you can create a REST Api, and send requests to that server for every event. At the backend app, you can store data in a database or send it to BigQuery directly.

I would recommend you to prepare list of events you want to analyze in BigQuery, and then if you already have it, you can send them here, so we can recommend more tangible alternatives.