# Event data, sent from via Google Tag Manager, not visible in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-tag-manager

I created some usual events in Google Tag Manager: Category, Action Label. I see them in Google Analytics Reports, but I don't see them in row Google Bigquery Streaming.

Here is an event in Tag Manager

[image]

I see it in Google Analytics Row
[image]

But nothing in Big Query
[image]

Has anybody met this problem? I have found absolutely nothing anywhere (but maybe I queried Google Search incorrectly).

Please help.

Comment: good question, Can you please provide an image showing your BigQuery Streaming export settings as defined in this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726?hl=en)

Comment: As I see, my Google Analytics is not linked with Bigquery. Can it be a problem? But Why I see other events?

I have many product events that are being sent with ga(send...). As I understand Tag Manager's events are almost the same.

Comment: Not sure about this as I don't have your view of the configuration. From the manual, you need to do the link to see the data. Just so we'll be focused on your specific question please do the link and advise if you see the data. After data if needed you can always open another question for OP to see

Comment: Please, could you show (an example screen) what does image have to contain and I'll put it here immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid errors while exporting data from GA to BigQuery you need to verify the following as described in Google official [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092)

### Avoiding export failures

> Failure to complete and maintain each of the following items can temporarily disable your account and cause daily BigQuery Exports from Analytics to fail. Keep in mind that we cannot reprocess failed exports that are caused by your failure to complete or maintain each of the following.
>
> Make sure the service account has the necessary permissions
>
> If at any point the service account (analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com) does not have EDIT access to the project, then data won’t be exported.
>   Ensure that billing is enabled.
>   If you created your BigQuery account using the free-trial option, make sure you upgrade to a paid account before the trial ends.
>   You can use a backup credit card to further avoid billing interruptions.
>   If you prefer to use Invoices instead of paying for Google Cloud using credit cards, contact Google Cloud Sales to discuss payment options.
>   Ensure that the BigQuery API is enabled.
>
> In Google Cloud Platform > your project > APIs & Services > Dashboard, make sure the BigQuery API is enabled.

If from your side everything is setup correctly I suggest you ask [Analytics 360 support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9026876?visit_id=636915355684812204-1569458847&rd=1) for additional help

Comment: Great. If my answer helped in anyway to the process and its appropriate please accept and vote up my answer. Best.