# How to send Google Tag Manager data directly to Data warehouse without Google Analytics

Tags: google-bigquery, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I am trying to send the build-in and user-defined variables directly to Big-query without using Google Analytics. Is there any easy way to do?

Expectation: Send GTM data directly to google Bigquery

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104501/how-to-send-data-from-google-tag-manager-gtm-to-google-bigquery

Comment: There might not be an easy way. If you don't want to use GA is fine. But what is your data format or tracking structure for your bigQuery?

Comment: Do you mean Web GTM or Server-Side GTM? The question has a tag for server-side, but you don't mention this in the text.